# What is this interpolation called?

Tags: python, image-processing, interpolation

I'm working on images, let's say that i have a row of the image matrix that has the values:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

I want to **resize** this image **using interpolation** so that the row becomes something like:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7]
```

Could someone tell me what is this interpolation technique called, and how can i possibly use it? I tried PIL.Image.resize resampling filters but they don't give me the results i'm looking for.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you describe, how did you get the resulting row?

Comment: Isn't it an upscaling technique?

Comment: @eightlay the resulting row is what i'm trying to get but don't know how, the idea is that the more we get away from the middle of the row the more the values are duplicated, in my example the middle is 4, so the 3 is only duplicated 2 times but the 1 is duplicated 4 times...

Comment: bad explanation. you don't care about repeating/duplicating anything. you care about a transfer function/mapping. -- so you want a mapping that involves a logarithm/exponentiation, a tan(), a sigmoid, or something like that? perhaps draw the function as y=f(x). then other people might get the idea. the answers I see below don't grasp that. they just literally give you code that reproduces that exact array in some arbitrary way, without reading your mind.

Comment: here, show something like that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnUTt.png

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like an interpolation but rather a repetition.

You can use a custom repeater and `numpy.repeat`:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
MAX, r = divmod(a.shape[0], 2)
rep = np.arange(1, MAX+r+1).astype(int)
rep = np.r_[rep[r:][::-1], rep]

out = np.repeat(a, rep)
```

output: `array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7])`

##### N-dimensional

```
a = np.arange(20).reshape(4, 5)

def custom_repeat(arr, axis=0):
    MAX, r = divmod(arr.shape[axis], 2)
    rep = np.arange(1, MAX+r+1).astype(int)
    rep = np.r_[rep[r:][::-1], rep]
    return np.repeat(arr, rep, axis=axis)
    
custom_repeat(custom_repeat(a, axis=0), axis=1)
```

output:

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  2,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  2,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4],
       [ 5,  5,  5,  6,  6,  7,  8,  8,  9,  9,  9],
       [10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14],
       [15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19],
       [15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19]])
```

Comment: Have you had a chance to give it a try?

Comment: my psychic powers say OP wants us to suggest math functions that look like a sigmoid (to *warp* an image then, not "resize" it), *not* to precisely replicate the array they gave. here's a plot of the "shape" they claim to want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnUTt.png

Comment: @Christoph then OP should provide context, more examples, and better explain the logic ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you're looking for

```
def my_procedure(current_list: list, index: int) -> list:
    index_copy = index
    table = []
    status_add = True

    for i in current_list:
        for _ in range(index):
            table.append(i)
        if status_add:
            index -= 1
        else:
            index += 1
        if index == 1 or index == index_copy:
            status_add = not status_add
    return table


x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

print(my_procedure(x, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly is pincushion distortion

[image]